# Who first proved that there is no five-digit perfect number?

Tags: mathematics, number-theory

A [perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number) is a positive integer that is equal to the sum of its positive divisors, excluding the number itself.  The first five perfect numbers are [6, 28, 496, 8128, and 33550336](https://oeis.org/A000396).

Nicomachus made several statements about perfect numbers c. 100 AD.  It is common to interpret one of these (eg, see the [MacTutor entry on perfect numbers](https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/HistTopics/Perfect_numbers/)) as stating that (in modern terminology)

> The *n*th perfect number has *n* digits.

As we see, this is incorrect because the 5th perfect number has 8 digits.
Nearly a millennium later c. 980 AD, [Al-Baghdadi](https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Al-Baghdadi/) wrote instead:

> He who affirms that there is only one perfect number in each power of 10 is wrong; there is no perfect number between ten thousand and one hundred thousand.

This is actually relatively easy to prove — **assuming** that all perfect numbers are even (which both Nicomachus and Al-Baghdadi also stated) and given the [Euclid-Euler theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%E2%80%93Euler_theorem) characterizing even perfect numbers.

However, in order to demonstrate that the fifth perfect number does not have five digits, it is also strictly-speaking necessary to demonstrate that there is no odd perfect number with five digits.  Who was the first to provide a sufficiently-precise analysis of odd perfect numbers to demonstrate that there does not exist a perfect number between 10,000 and 100,000, as asserted by Al-Baghdadi?  Or more importantly, *when*?

*Remark*: The history of perfect numbers is littered with false claims as well as bold, still-unproven assertions.  And of course the standards of proof have evolved considerably over the millennia.  However, as a minimum bar for "sufficiently-precise", I would like there to be *any* analysis of odd perfect numbers whatsoever beyond the claim that they don't exist.